# Powershell: Faster version of xml.parentNode.RemoveChild

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm trying to drop nodes from a very large XLF-File (which is basically an XML file) via powershell.
The structure is (simplified) always the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xliff>
  <file>
    <body>
      <group>
        <trans-unit>
          <source>asd</source>
          <target>asd</target>
        </trans-unit>
        <trans-unit>
          <source> </source>
          <target> </target>
        </trans-unit>
        <trans-unit>
          <source>asd</source>
          <target>asdf</target>
        </trans-unit>
        </group>
    </body>
  </file>
</xliff>
```

Now i want to remove all nodes in this file where source and target are equal.

Here is what i have so far:

Match function:

```
function Match{
    param(
        $sourceNode,$targetNode
    )
    #do this because empty string as xml value is of type xmlElement and fails to compare
    if ($sourceNode.innerText -eq " ") {
        $source = $sourceNode.innerText
    }
    else {
        $source = $sourceNode
    }
    if ($targetNode.innerText -eq " ") {
        $target = $targetNode.innerText
    }
    else {
        $target = $targetNode
    }
    return $source -eq $target
}
```

Code to remove nodes:

```
$xml = [xml]((Get-Content $xmlPath -Encoding UTF8).Replace("trans-unit", "transunit"))
$xml.xliff.file.body.group.transunit | ForEach-Object {
    if (Match $_.source $_.target) {
        $_.parentNode.RemoveChild($_) | Out-Null
    }
}
$xml = [xml]($xml.OuterXml.Replace("transunit", "trans-unit"))
$xml.Save($outPath)
```

This works, but unfortunately it is very slow as the file has roughly 300 000 nodes. It is important that the nodes keep their attributes while saving to further process the file later.

A faster approach which I was not able to finish is the following:

```
$xml = [xml]([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($xmlPath).Replace("trans-unit", "transunit"))
$filteredNodes = $xml.xliff.file.body.group.transunit | Where-Object {
    !(Match $_.source $_.target)
}

???

$xml = [xml]($xml.OuterXml.Replace("transunit", "trans-unit"))
$xml.Save($outPath)
```

to get a List containing all XmlNodes where target and source are different, but unfortunately I was not able to pass this list back into the xml document

Is there a faster way to remove those matching nodes from the file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with your approach.

1. NEVER use `[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($xmlPath)` or `Get-Content $xmlPath` to read an XML file. This is wrong because it kills the file encoding auto-detection that is built into XML, and it's wasteful because the XML parser is perfectly able to read the file on its own - reading it into a PowerShell variable first serves no purpose.

   Always load XML files with the parser directly:

   ```ps1
   $doc = New-Object xml
   $doc.Load($xmlPath)
   ```
2. You should use XPath to select candidates for deletion:

   ```ps1
   $same = $doc.selectNodes('//trans-unit[source = target]')
   ```

   These are easy to iterate over and remove:

   ```ps1
   foreach ($n in $same) {
       $n.parentNode.removeChild($n)
   }
   ```

   This is about as fast as it gets when processing the file with .NET's `XmlDocument`.
3. Don't call `string.Replace()` on XML source code. Just don't.

---

You can use XSLT to strip nodes from a document. There's a good chance that this performs better:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" />

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="trans-unit[source = target]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Usage in PowerShell goes something like this:

```ps1
using namespace System.Xml

$xsl = [Xsl.XslCompiledTransform]::new();
$xsl.Load('C:\path\to\above.xsl')

$xmlIn = [XmlTextReader]::new('C:\path\to\input.xml')
$xmlOut = [XmlTextWriter]::Create('C:\path\to\output.xml')
$xsl.Transform($xmlIn, $xmlOut)

$xmlIn.Close()
$xmlIn.Dispose()

$xmlOut.Close()
$xmlOut.Dispose()
```

Caveat with using the .NET objects directly is that you need to supply full paths. Relative paths won't work. You can use `(Join-Path (Get-Location) 'filename.xml')` to create a full path where needed.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a ton! Do you have any tips on how to proceed xml files with a namespace? the actual xliff-node looks like this: `<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2 xliff-core-1.2-transitional.xsd">` and unfortunately, xPath does not find anything as long as this is inside the file.

Comment: @MichaelVillani There are countless examples how to handle an XML default namespace with PowerShell and XPath, if you search around you will find them. For me, even searching "XML default namespace with PowerShell and XPath" already gives a useful first hit on Google.

Comment: Ok, thank you for that tip, that got me in the right direction. Just in case you're interested: The .net approach takes about 5 hours while the xsl approach takes about 10 seconds for my use case where around 70% of the nodes get dropped.

Comment: @MichaelVillani That's... *way* better than I expected. Does the "5 hours" refer to your PowerShell approach, or mine?

Comment: You can try to use [msxsl.exe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21714), which should be even faster than .NET, and less awkward to use from PowerShell, too.

Comment: I did not try your powershell approach per se, but as the expensive part usually was the deleting, the duration should be about the same. Even if yours was twice as fast as mine, your XSL approach would still beat it by a lot.

Comment: @Michael I'm pretty sure that the expensive part was your creative way of selecting nodes and the `Foreach-Object` pipeline, not the deletion itself, that's why I had asked. That the XSLT is faster is not much of a surprise. Did you try msxsl.exe? If not, give it a go, it's a stand-alone executable, there's not much needed to try it out.